# How do I allow permissions so that i can run my python server?

Tags: python, django, server

I was trying to practice using django,

when I executed  `python3 manage.py runserver`, I received a permission denied when trying and I'm not sure what that means.

I have seen this before, but I am not sure how I would be able to allow permissions. I thought I enabled everything in start up but I feel I am missing something.

I will post a picture [here from when I went into the folder I started and tried to run the server.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3V6C.png)

Comment: you need create virtual environment then activate it

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using sudo before the "python3 ..." command?

(I can't add this to comments due to my low reputation)